# How to write the SQL query so that it doesn't have to run for each day?

Tags: sql, join, vertica

I am using Vertica Enterprise for my warehouse.

I have three tables.

**Table #1** - Students

[image: Students Table]

Table #2 - Address of Students

[image]

Table #3 - Homework progress of Students done for the day. (Note: some of students might be absent on that day). Homework progress column is in %.

[image]

**Desired output**

I want all the days that exists in table 3 and all the students from table 1 along with their addresses from table 2 in a single table.

[image]

Here is my attempt but I have to run the query for each day. Meaning I have to keep changing `HOMEWORK.day = '2023-11-01'` and `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(20231101), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DAY_` for each run.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_4 
    SELECT 
        TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(20231101),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DAY_,
        A.ID AS ID,
        A.NAME AS NAME,
        B.ADDRESS AS ADDRESS,
        NVL(C.HOMEWORK_PROGRESS,0.0) AS PROGRESS
    FROM 
        STUDENTS AS STUDENT
    INNER JOIN 
        ADDRESS AS ADDRESS ON STUDENT.ID = ADDRESS.ID
    LEFT JOIN 
        HOMEWORK AS HOMEWORK ON STUDENT.ID = HOMEWORK.ID AND HOMEWORK.DAY = '2023-11-01'
```

I want to rewrite it so that I can just do `HOMEWORK.DAY BETWEEN '2023-11-01' AND '2023-11-30'` and let it run by itself.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) - you should use **intuitive** and obvious aliases - e.g. `Students AS s`, `Homework AS h` that don't require you to **know** which alias is what - but it's clear from just looking at the alias....

Answer (score 0):

I found no better solution than cross joining all distinct id-s from the progress table with all distinct dates from the progress table in a sub select (a CTE), and then left-joining the progress table with that CTE:

```
WITH
```

-- your data, don't use in final query ...

```
stud(id,nam) AS (
            SELECT 1,'John'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Kenny'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3,'Westly'
  UNION ALL SELECT 4,'Arthur'
  UNION ALL SELECT 5,'Tom'
)
,                                                                               
addr(id,addr) AS (
            SELECT 1,'North'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,'West'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3,'East'
  UNION ALL SELECT 4,'South East'
  UNION ALL SELECT 5,'South West'
)
,
progress(dt,id,progress) AS (    
            SELECT DATE '2023-01-01',1,0.5
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-01-01',2,0.7
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-01-01',3,1.0
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-11-02',1,0.8
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-11-02',2,0.9
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-11-02',3,1.0
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2023-11-02',4,0.2
)
```

-- end of input; real query starts here

-- replace following comma with "WITH"

```
,  -- or WITH for stand-alone query
all_stud_dt AS (
  SELECT
    id
  , dt
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT dt FROM progress) dt
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM progress) id
)
SELECT
  all_stud_dt.dt
, all_stud_dt.id
, addr
, NVL(progress,0) AS progress
FROM all_stud_dt
JOIN addr USING(id)
LEFT JOIN progress USING(id,dt)
ORDER BY 1,2
;
-- out      dt     | id |    addr    | progress 
-- out ------------+----+------------+----------
-- out  2023-01-01 |  1 | North      | 0.5
-- out  2023-01-01 |  2 | West       | 0.7
-- out  2023-01-01 |  3 | East       | 1.0
-- out  2023-01-01 |  4 | South East | 0.0
-- out  2023-11-02 |  1 | North      | 0.8
-- out  2023-11-02 |  2 | West       | 0.9
-- out  2023-11-02 |  3 | East       | 1.0
-- out  2023-11-02 |  4 | South East | 0.2
```

Answer (score -1):

did you try the obvious one :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_4 
SELECT C.DAY AS DAY_
,A.ID AS ID
,A.NAME AS NAME
,B.ADDRESS AS ADDRESS
,NVL(C.HOMEWORK_PROGRESS,0.0) AS PROGRESS
FROM STUDENTS AS A
INNER JOIN ADDRESS AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN HOMEWORK AS C ON A.ID = C.ID 
WHERE C.DAY BETWEEN '2023-11-01' AND '2023-11-30'
```

?

Comment: using 'WHERE' clause for the days from table 'C' does not return all lists of students. 

Using 'WHERE' here is same as 'INNER JOIN' between students table and homework table where homework table does not have all students for each day.